# ASP.Net Web Application deployment steps

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, deployment, iis-7

I have the following two folder/files:

1. .bak File
2. Deployment Folder containing Account, App_GlobalResources, App_Themes, bin, HelpFiles, Master, Media Scripts, Styles, etc. folders and Configuaration files

All this is related to a ASP.Net Web Application. How do I deploy this application on **IIS**. Steps?

**Note:** I don't have access to VS. But I do have access to **VS Tools for Applications 2.0**

**Edit 1:** I followed the steps laid out perfectly by @YashSaraiya

However, after following those steps when I right-clicked on my Application -> Manage Application -> Browse, I got the following screen:

[image]

I believe, I will have to change some properties in web.config file. But I don't know what changes I will have to make (except for the **connection string**).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to follow (Point no. 2):

1. Open Start -> inetmgr
2. Expand the server (under Connections Tab). On expanding you will see "Application Pools" and "Sites"
3. Expand Sites and Right-click "Default Web Site" and select "Add Application..." option (On doing so, a new window will pop-up)
4. Enter the Alias (ABC for example), Physical Path (Path to your Deployment Folder) and click OK (A new site will be created)
5. Right-click "Application Pools" (above Sites) and select "Add Application Pool" (This will open a new window)
6. Select the .NET Framework version, Select Managed Pipeline Mode and Enter the Name. Click Ok.

---

Steps to Follow (Point No. 1):

1. Open SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio)
2. Connect to your Server
3. Right-click Databases (Visible inside Object Explorer) and select "Restore Database". This will open a new window
4. Select From device under "Source for Restore"
5. Click "..." besides From device option to browse for .bak file. This will open a new window
6. Click on "Add" button
7. Select your .bak File and click OK
8. Repeat steps 6 and 7. Now you will see some data added under "Select the backup to restore"
9. Check the box for which you want to restore a database and click ok

Hope this helps!!!