# Changes to be made to **web.config** after deploying ASP.NET Web Application on IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, deployment

I followed steps given by @YashSaraiya in my this post: [ASP.Net Web Application deployment steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34433426/asp-net-web-application-deployment-steps)

However, after following those steps in **inetmgr** when I right-clicked on my Application -> Manage Application -> Browse, I got the following screen:

[image]

I believe, I will have to change some properties in web.config file. But I don't know what changes I will have to make (except for the **connection string**).

Can anyone help me know What changes I need to make to successfully deploy my application?

**Edit 2:** After properly installing ASP.Net in IIS and adding required roles, I got the following error screen:

[image]

Comment: On default IIS installation, such sections are strictly locked down in applicationHost.config. Unless you follow Microsoft's documentation to unlock those sections, such error messages are expected. That's why I hate those blog posts which do not make it very clear to their readers.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the issue seems to be in your handlers sections where you tried to override values but that is not allowed by the parent configuration file.

When you observe the ConfigError message, that it was explained to you ;)

EDIT
The new issue explain That your application pool is in integrated mode and use as it dors handlers for its mode but it has found managerpipelinehandler That is not for its mode. Just remove it from the list and retry to browsethe application.

Comment: Under which tag do I look for changes in my web.config file?

Comment: First you have to determine if by removing the overriden section it works. In your case it seems that is <handlers> section which is the cause of issue

Comment: Does IE7 support "ChartImageHandler" ?

Comment: That isn't related to IE or whatever browser. If one dosn't support ChartImageHabdler is only IIS according to its configuration. Handler doesn't take in charge by browser only by the server. What Is your idea behind this question ?

Comment: I was of the view that maybe ChartImageHandler is not supported in IE7... Also, I found out that ASP.Net is not completely installed in IIS... This might be causing Errors.. I am now installing ASP.NET on IIS... Let's see if that makes my application work fine

Comment: `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -i` I ran this command and found out that ASP.net was still not properly installed and so I made a fresh installation and it is now working fine

Comment: ok perfect. Don't forget to approve the answer to mark your question solved. Thanks to have put the last command solved definitively the issue .